# Need to apply formula in power bi report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

[image][image: Output][image: Excel data][image]I have a table in excel, where there are 3 columns as mentioned. Closed column is calculated column, in which I have applied formula in Row1- `IFERROR(IF(B2="","",B2),"")`
where B2=71 and the output is 71(closed column).

In  Row2 of closed column, I have applied formula- `IFERROR(IF(01/2020=01/2020, 284-71, 284),"")`/ `IFERROR(IF(A3=A2, B3-B2, B3),"")`. Output is 213 and so on...

Same data I have in power bi, Report month and open column. I need to create a calculated column to get the closed column data. Please help me with the formula to apply in power bi.[image: Excel data]

Comment: di you have any id or index like column?

Comment: Yes, I have index column in power bi

Comment: Please check my answer as I used same Index column in DAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you have a **Index or ID** column in your data, just use that column. Here I have added a **Index** column to maintain the ordering between rows and the data looks as below-

[image]

Now create this below measure-

```
Closed = 

VAR previous_row_open = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[open]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name,
            your_table_name[report month]
        ),
        your_table_name[Index] = MIN(your_table_name[Index]) - 1
    )
) + 0

VAR previous_row_report_month = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[report month]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name,
            your_table_name[report month]
        ),
        your_table_name[Index] = MIN(your_table_name[Index]) - 1
    )
)

RETURN
IF(
    previous_row_report_month = BLANK(),
    MIN(your_table_name[open]),
    MIN(your_table_name[open]) - previous_row_open
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

**Here** is the code for **Custom Column**

```
Closed_column = 

VAR current_index = your_table_name_2[Index]

VAR previous_row_open = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name_2[open]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name_2,
            your_table_name_2[report month]
        ),
        your_table_name_2[Index] = current_index - 1
    )
) + 0

VAR previous_row_report_month = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name_2[report month]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name_2,
            your_table_name_2[report month]
        ),
        your_table_name_2[Index] = current_index - 1
    )
)

RETURN
IF(
    previous_row_report_month = BLANK(),
    your_table_name_2[open],
    your_table_name_2[open] - previous_row_open
)
```

Comment: I'm getting only 71 as output

Comment: Hi @KiranPatel, you are creating Measure or Column? The given code is for a Measure.

Comment: I'm creating column

Comment: Got the result using measure but -ve values are not comming correct . Rest everything is correct

Comment: Please check the updated answer with code for Custom Column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223270/discussion-between-r-r-and-kiran-patel).